# Behavior of std::cin on failure

Tags: c++, cin

New to C++ and I was checking the behavior of `cin` on unexpected inputs and wrote the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main() {
    
    int num = -1;

    cin >> num;
    cout << num << "\n";

    char alph = 'z';

    cin >> alph;
    cout << alph << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

So, its supposed to take a number and then a character.
Here are the results on different types of inputs

```
5 a
5
a
```

```
5a
5
a
```

```
aa
0
z
```

First one is expected.

In second one, I read [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/stdcin-and-handling-invalid-input/) that since `std::cin` is able to extract `5` the operation will be successful leaving `a` in the buffer. So, that `a` is taken by our character input.

I am not able to understand the third case. Here the first `cin` extraction fails.

Then what happens? Because the second `cin` doesn't do anything. Are none of the `a`'s being left in the buffer.

Comment: @Ch3steR What about the next input operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very link you cited explains what's happening:

> https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/stdcin-and-handling-invalid-input/
>
> When the user enters input in response to an extraction operation,
> that data is placed in a buffer inside of std::cin.
>
> When the extraction operator is used, the following procedure happens:
>
> - If there is data already in the input buffer, that data is used for extraction.
> - If the input buffer contains no data, the user is asked to input data for extraction (this is the case most of the time). When the user
>   hits enter, a ‘\n’ character will be placed in the input buffer.
> - operator>> extracts as much data from the input buffer as it can into the variable (ignoring any leading whitespace characters, such as
>   spaces, tabs, or ‘\n’).
> - Any data that can not be extracted is left in the input buffer for the next extraction.

So far, so good.  The article continues:

> [Upon an input error] std::cin goes immediately into “failure mode”,
> but also assigns the closest in-range value to the variable.
> Consequently, x is left with the assigned value of 32767.
>
> Additional inputs are skipped, leaving y with the initialized value of
> 0.

This explains the "0" you're seeing.  It also explains why "z" wasn't replaced with "a".

Comment: So basically the program is done and dusted if any of the `cin` goes into failure mode. Never encountered this since most of the programs in books are for exact inputs

Comment: Also, hence the `a`'s being left in the buffer or not will not matter then. Right?

Comment: @mr.loop yes, they are left in the buffer, in case the program decides to `clear()` the failure state and try again with proper variable types.

Comment: Okay, will look more into that

Comment: Again: the same [link](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/stdcin-and-handling-invalid-input/) you cited has a good example, under "Putting it all together": `std::cin.clear(); // put us back in 'normal' operation mode`