# When int age = -1, and I enter in an invalid input for age using cin (ie. asdf), why does the age return as 0 and not -1?

Tags: c++

Using 64-bit Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS | Using Eclipse IDE Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
Build id: 20220609-1112 | *Built using Linux GCC toolchain* |
[Code alongside PDF of Stroustrup textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLLHU.png)

Code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    int age = -1;                   // program would still function if var was not assigned
    string first_name = "???";      // a value, we are giving them values so that an error
                                    // message of sorts is implemented by doing so
    cout << "Please enter your first name and age\nie. Quagmire 69\n";

    cin >> first_name;
    cin >> age;

    cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")\n";

    return 0;
}
```

In my case, after building and running, I input `420 as;ldfkj`.

The program's output was `Hello, 420 (age 0)`.

Why was the output `0` and not `-1` as specified by `int age = -1;`?

EDIT: Is the textbook incorrect, or did I misunderstand? The textbook seems to expect that `-1` should be returned. The book was written in 2014.

(Bonus question below)

> How could I enter an erroneous input for `first_name`? I've tried special characters on the number keys, Zalgo, and even emojis, and they all seemed to output correctly.

Comment: _"...If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), zero is written to value and failbit is set...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Comment: For the first name, you could try Ctrl+D or Ctrl+Z (depending on your platform).

Comment: @RichardCritten is the textbook incorrect, or did I misunderstand? The textbook seems to expect that ```-1``` should be returned. The book was written in 2014.

Comment: @StrawberryMustard in __Defect reports__ (in the above link) _"...C++98 value was unchanged on extraction failure..."_ so a 2014 book is probably wrong as it should by that time be referencing C++11

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69140185/behavior-of-stdcin-on-failure

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++98 had a bug, the book may have been written in late 2011, early 2012 and the author didn't use a C++11 compiler to test.

```
cin >> first_name;
```

This reads characters from input until non-whitespace is followed by white space.

```
cin >> age;
```

This reads digits into an integer, or 0 if the first character is not a digit.

Bonus Question:
Emoji, special characters, etc are all just non-whitespace. So they will be read into the string. However you can lock up the program by typing characters until your terminal can accept no more. At that point it will just beep. At that point you can't even hit return. ;-)

Comment: Ironic! This textbook was largely written by Stroustrup, the creator of C++